# RSpecでモックを使用した際にテストしたいコードより先expectを実行する理由が分からない。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, mock

下記のテストコードを作成したのですが、 `get :index params` の下に `expect`のコードを配置すると値がないとエラーが表示されます。
他のテストコード(モックを使用しない)では `expext` の上にテストしたいコードがあったのに不思議です。 `expect`　でモックを立ててそこにテストしたいコードが実行され値を取得するイメージに　なるのでしょうか。
詳しい方見て頂けないでしょうか？
よろしくお願い致します。

エラー内容

```
Failure/Error: @notes = @project.notes.search(params[:term])
       #<InstanceDouble(Project) (anonymous)> received unexpected message :notes with (no args)
```

テストコード

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe NotesController, type: :controller do
  let(:user) { double("user") }
  # project_owner, project_idに反応するようになる
  let(:project) { instance_double("Project", owner: user, id: "123") }

  before do
    # allowにスタブ化したいメソッドを持つインスタンスを指定する
    # receiveにスタブ化したいメソッドのシンボルを指定して
    # それが返す値を指定する。
    allow(request.env["warden"]).
      to receive(:authenticate!).and_return(user)
    allow(controller).
      to receive(:current_user).and_return(user)
    allow(Project).
      to receive(:find).with("123").and_return(project)
  end
  describe "#index" do
    # 入力されたキーワードでメモを検索すること
    it "searches notes by the provided keyword" do
      # 参考記事だと　allowと一緒に使用されるallowがitの中で使用される
      # projaect.notes.search みたいなチェーンになるその引数は 'rorate tires'
      # このexpectはアプリを動作させる前に追加しないとテストがパスしない、no argsと言われる
      # モックを先に立ててそこにアクセスするイメージなのかもしれない知らないけど
      expect(project).to receive_message_chain(:notes, :search).with("rorate tires")
      get :index,
        params: { project_id: project.id, term: "rorate tires" }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

スパイと呼ばれるもので、テストしたい処理を実行した後にその処理を監視しているので、中身を確認することができる。
みたいなイメージと思われる。

#### 参考

[RSpecのスパイ(Spy)を理解する](https://qiita.com/johnslith/items/e0f8a55b7913358670fc)